# Is it possible to make a 3d program in vb.Net

Tags: python, vb.net, 3d

I'm a bit unsure on wherever this is possible or not, but is it possibe to make a 3d graphics and animation program in Visual basic (Using Visual Studio 2013), and if so, what modules do I need?

I've looked into modules already, but the only one I found was way over my budget.

I've also heard that it's possible in Python 3 and I may have to use this language, instead.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to use python it's possible you can use DirectX SDK for C# and VB.net but almost all tutorials in C#. Download SDK From Here:-
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11471

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was possible!

Answer (score 0):

acutally you should be able to use any .Net Library with VB.NET. i never tried it because i just use C#, thats the major Language for .Net, and my suggestion for using .Net as well. Most examples you find are in C#.

You may want to take a look at [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/)
you could also start working directly with OpenGL or DirectX, but MonoGame has a stronger abstraction, what makes it a lot easier for you.

Actually you should be able to develop 3D graphics/Animation in every major objecr orientated programming Language.